# Upgrading to Alamofire 5.x

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am attempting to upgrade to Alamofire 5.x and one line has me blocked:

```
private static func request<T: Codable> (_ urlConvertible: URLRequestConvertible) -> Observable<T> {
    return Observable<T>.create { observer in
        let request = AF.request(urlConvertible).responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<T>) in ... }
    }
}
```

The response does not seem to be a single type anymore as XCode is complaining of **"Generic type 'DataResponse' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)"**

Thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Alamofire 5rc1, `DataResponse` and the other response types became doubly generic, to both the value serialized from the response and the error type produced. By default Alamofire's response handlers will always produce `AFError` error values, so there are now `AF*Response` `typealias`es that default to that error type.

Additionally, you shouldn't use `responseJSON` if you have `Codable` types, just use `responseDecodable`:

```swift
private static func request<T: Codable> (_ urlConvertible: URLRequestConvertible) -> Observable<T> {
    return Observable<T>.create { observer in
        let request = AF.request(urlConvertible).responseDecodable(of: T.self) { response in ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the case of response, would you not cast it such as: (response: DataResponse<T>) in ... per your post in https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2180 and if so, how do you resolve the issue of it looking for 2 parameters.

Comment: `responseDecodable` automatically uses the `AFDataResponse` type, which has a default `AFError` error type, so the type is inferred through the use of the `of` parameter`. That comment predates this newer API and drove the development of it.

Comment: Cool, that is what I needed to know ... Thank you for the response.